# Lua game development, table seems to delete itself after each interation

Tags: list, lua, lua-table

What I am trying to do is a little addon which would let me know how much time I have spent casting during combat in %,

```
function() 
local spell, _, _, _, _, endTime = UnitCastingInfo("player")
-- getting information from the game itself whether im "Casting"

local inCombat = UnitAffectingCombat("player")
-- getting information form the game if combat is true (1) or not (nil)

local casting = {}

local sum = 0
if inCombat == 1 then
    if spell then 
        table.insert(casting, 1)
    else
        table.insert(casting, 0)
    end
else
    for k in pairs (casting) do
        casting [k] = nil 
    end
end
for i=1, #casting, 1 do
    sum = sum + casting[i]

end
return( sum / #casting ) end

-- creating a list which adds 1 every frame I am casting and I am in combat,
-- or adds 0 every frame I'm not casting and I'm not in combat.
-- Then I sum all the numbers and divide it by the number of inputs to figure 
-- out how much % I have spent "casting".
-- In case the combat condition is false, delete the list
```

For some reason these numbers don't add up at all, I only see "1" when both conditions are satisfied, or 0 if the combat condition is satisfied.

There might be some better approach I'm sure, but I am kind of new to lua and programming in general.

Comment: Your `local casting = {}` must be an upvalue or global.  For now, you are creating new table `casting` on every frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot, completely missed it. In case someone would have the same problem in the future the fix is "casting_ = {}"

Comment: I'd suggest to replace `local casting = {}` with `casting = casting or {}`

Comment: Why don't you just add 1 (or 0) to your sum variable in the first place? In the end that seems to be all you do anyway, right? Or you could at least use an integer instead of a table for `casting` and just add to that.

Comment: If you're iterating over **consecutive** integer keys (1, 2, 3, ...) use `ipairs` instead of `pairs`, it's faster *and* you don't get string keys, so you can use those to store some extra information if the situation demands it.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're new to Lua, so I will attempt to explain in detail what is wrong and how it can be improved, so brace yourself for a long read.

I assume that your function will be called every frame/step/tick/whateveryouwanttocallit of your game. Since you set `sum = 0` and `casting = {}` at the beginning of the function, this will be done **every time** the function is called. That's why you always get 0 or 1 in the end.

### Upvalues to the rescue!

Lua has this nice thing called lexical scoping. I won't go into much detail, but the basic idea is: If a variable is accessible (in scope) when a function is defined, that function remembers that variable, no matter where it is called. For example:

```
local foo
do
  local var = 10
  foo = function() return var end
end
print(bar) -- nil
print(foo()) -- 10
```

You can also assign a new value to the variable and the next time you call the function, it will still have that new value. For example, here's a simple counter function:

```
local counter
do
  count = 0
  counter = function() count = count + 1; return count; end
end
print(counter()) -- 1
print(counter()) -- 2
-- etc.
```

Applying that to your situation, what are the values that need to persist from one call to the next?

- Number of ticks spent in combat
- Number of ticks spent casting

Define those two values *outside* of your function, and increment / read / reset them as needed; it will persist between repeated calls to your function.

Things to keep in mind:

- You need to reset those counters when the player is no longer casting and/or in combat, or they will just continue where they left off.
- `casting` doesn't need to be a table. Tables are slow compared to integers, even if you reuse them. If you need to count stuff, a number is more than enough. Just make `casting = 0` when not in combat and increase it by 1 when in combat.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for feedback everyone, in the end after your suggestions and some research my code looks like this and works great:

```
function() 
local spell, _, _, _, startTime, endTime, _, _, _ = UnitCastingInfo("player")
local inCombat = UnitAffectingCombat("player")
local inLockdown = InCombatLockdown()
local _, duration, _, _ = GetSpellCooldown("Fireball")
casting = casting or  {}
local sum = 0
if inCombat == 1 or inLockdown == 1 then 
    if spell or duration  ~= 0 then 
        casting[#casting+1] = 1  
    elseif spell == nil or duration == 0  then
        casting[#casting+1] = 0   
    end  
else
    local next = next
    local k = next(casting)
    while k ~= nil do
        casting[k] = nil
        k = next(casting, k)
    end
end
for i=1, #casting, 1 do
    sum = sum + casting[i]
end
return(("%.1f"):format( (sum / #casting)*100 ).. "%%") end
```

what i noticed is there was a problem with reseting the table in the original code:

```
for k in pairs (casting) do
    casting [k] = nil
```

it seemed like either some zeros stayed there, or the table size didnt "shrink" i dont know.

Maybe intereger would be faster then a table, but honestly i dont see any performance issues even when the table gets ridicolously big (5 min, 60 fps, thats 18k inputs) also for the sake of learning a new language its better to do it harder way in my opinion

Regards